# would hipchat bot "lita" and/or "hubot" work via port 443?

Tags: xmpp, hubot, hipchat, lita

I am trying to connect `hipchat` bot `lita` and/or `hubot`.

- the XMPP libs have port hard coded to `5222` but I've changed it to `443` - I'm getting errors now.
- I can post the errors I get but before that I wanted to check if port 443 would work, as it is connecting for but getting disconnect right away with `broken pipe` message.

Answer (score 0):

No, it won't work that way, since hubot doesn't support the XMPP-BOSH protocol. You can follow [these instructions](https://confluence.atlassian.com/hipchatkb/external-xmpp-ports-5222-5223-disabled-by-default-in-hipchat-server-2-0-7-859442760.html) to re-enable port 5222 in your HipChat Server:

```
hipchat network --enable-xmpp-ports
```